# Unparseable Date Kotlin with September Month with MMM format

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Ican't understand why I am getting error on Following code on September Month

```
    var dateFormat: SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy")
    val    vdate:String="09-Sep-2022"
    val ndate :Date = dateFormat.parse(vdate)
    sampeltextview.text=ndate.toString()
```

errori am getting is :  Unparseable date: "09-Sep-2022"

But when I change Month  other than September for ex. Jun , Jul ect.

Comment: have you tried "Sept" instead of Sep?

Comment: yeah its working with Sept any specific reason there?

Comment: It is depending on `AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames` which is different in different language

Comment: Not answering your question, I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).